# Setting the parent id with has many ember js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models Recipe and Ingredient. They have has many and belongs to association.

Recipe : Id, title. Ingredient: id, name, recipe_id

I create nested form with recipe and ingredient. I can set recipe_id in each ingredient on client side but I think it's bad idea cause user can hack and change this id.

**What is the right way to set parent id on saving to backend?**

recipes_new_controller.js.coffee

```
App.RecipesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  save: ->
    console.log "save recipe"
    @transaction.commit()
```

new.emblem

```
h1 Create recipe

form
  div
    label{bindAttr for='title.elementId'} Title
    Ember.TextField valueBinding='title' name='title' viewName='title'

  div
    label{bindAttr for='about.elementId'} About
    Ember.TextArea valueBinding='about' name='about' viewName='about'

  #ingredients
    h3 Ingredients
    each ingredient in content.ingredients
      .control-group
        .controls
          Ember.TextField valueBinding='ingredient.about'
          a{ action removeIngredient ingredient target='controller' } href='#' Remove
    div
      a{ action addIngredient target='controller' } href='#' Add Ingredient

  button.btn.btn-success{ action save this } Create
  button.btn.btn-inverse{ action cancel this } Cancel
```

Comment: Are you using ember-data ?

Comment: Yes i use ember-data in project.

Comment: In this cas, I this you have just to define the DS.belongsTo() on the child, and it should work perfectly, adding automatically the recipe_id in the Ingredient.

Comment: " I can set recipe_id in each ingredient on client side but I think it's bad idea cause user can hack and change this id". I don't really see how things could be done differently. A user can hack the record or when the XHR request is made. This `recipe_id` has to come from the client side. The best you can do is to make sure on the server side that the recipe belongs to the user that generated the request.

Comment: I can't understand how to set in ingredients recipe id on client side in my form. My form is written in first post. Help me please!